# Ubuntu Hadoop cannot find JAVA_HOME

Tags: bash, ubuntu, hadoop, java-home

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

gives me`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`
and I have `export JAVA_HOME= /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` in my /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh. 
However when I run `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop` I got the following error:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 25: export: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle': not a valid identifier
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
```

I thought I had my JAVA_HOME correctly set, anyone can tell me where I did wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that space between the equals sign and the path in your `export`. Shell scripting can be a little finicky about that kind of thing.

Answer (score -1):

This Must happened for Multiple JAVA_HOME Defined please check it in .bashrc file or .profile